# Why does my python venv return exit status 1

Tags: python, python-venv

I am trying to create a virtual environment, but its not working. I am on a M1 MacOS and running the `python -m venv myworld` command

This is the error I am getting:
`Error: Command '[ '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1`

I tried to sudo install but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there might be an issue with the ensurepip module in your Python installation. One solution you can try is to reinstall Python using Homebrew, which is a package manager for macOS.

Comment: How should I do it? I am checking the versions of python3 and pip3 they are all installed already on my computer

Comment: Install Homebrew if you haven't already by running this command in your terminal: /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"                                    Once Homebrew is installed, run the following command to install Python:                      brew install python

Comment: After the installation is complete, try creating a virtual environment again using the python3 -m venv myworld command.
If you still encounter issues, you can try creating the virtual environment using conda or pyenv instead of the built-in venv module. These tools can help manage different Python versions and environments.